# Forwarding Google PubSub messages from one topic to another

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

It would be very handy to be able to forward messages from one topic to another without requiring custom code.

For example, instead of a service subscribing to multiple topics, if all topics could forward messages to a single topic, implementing the subscriber would be much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way to forward messages from one topic to another in Google Cloud Pub/Sub. One would have to write the code manually or via [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/).